# Set Windows Logs max size with Powershell Limit-Eventlog

Tags: powershell, windows-server

Aim to script the increase of the default size of all the Windows Logs and change some other properties. Used to do it with `wevtutil` but can't get this to work in 2016, so switched to Powershell's `Limit-Eventlog`. Fresh Windows Server 2016 install with latest updates.

Start with the default log properties:

```
PS> Get-Eventlog -List

+--------+--------+-------------------+---------+------------------------+
| Max(K) | Retain |  OverflowAction   | Entries |          Log           |
+--------+--------+-------------------+---------+------------------------+
|    300 |      0 | OverwriteAsNeeded |   2,599 | Application            |
| 20,480 |      0 | OverwriteAsNeeded |       0 | HardwareEvents         |
|    512 |      7 | OverwriteAsNeeded |       0 | Internet Explorer      |
| 20,480 |      0 | OverwriteAsNeeded |       0 | Key Management Service |
| 20,480 |      0 | OverwriteAsNeeded |  10,390 | Security               |
| 20,480 |      0 | OverwriteAsNeeded |   3,561 | System                 |
| 15,360 |      0 | OverwriteAsNeeded |     360 | Windows PowerShell     |
+--------+--------+-------------------+---------+------------------------+
```

Change one log at a time, no errors:

```
PS> Limit-Eventlog -Logname Application -MaximumSize 200MB -OverflowAction OverwriteAsNeeded
PS> Limit-Eventlog -Logname HardwareEvents -MaximumSize 200MB -OverflowAction OverwriteAsNeeded
PS> Limit-Eventlog -Logname "Internet Explorer" -MaximumSize 200MB -OverflowAction OverwriteAsNeeded
PS> Limit-Eventlog -Logname "Key Management Service" -MaximumSize 200MB -OverflowAction OverwriteAsNeeded
PS> Limit-Eventlog -Logname Security -MaximumSize 200MB -OverflowAction OverwriteAsNeeded
PS> Limit-Eventlog -Logname System -MaximumSize 200MB -OverflowAction OverwriteAsNeeded
PS> Limit-Eventlog -Logname "Windows Powershell" -MaximumSize 200MB -OverflowAction OverwriteAsNeeded
PS> Get-Eventlog -List

+---------+--------+-------------------+---------+------------------------+
| Max(K)  | Retain |  OverflowAction   | Entries |          Log           |
+---------+--------+-------------------+---------+------------------------+
| 204,800 |      0 | OverwriteAsNeeded |   2,599 | Application            |
| 204,800 |      0 | OverwriteAsNeeded |       0 | HardwareEvents         |
| 204,800 |      0 | OverwriteAsNeeded |       0 | Internet Explorer      |
| 204,800 |      0 | OverwriteAsNeeded |       0 | Key Management Service |
| 204,800 |      0 | OverwriteAsNeeded |  10,395 | Security               |
| 204,800 |      0 | OverwriteAsNeeded |   3,561 | System                 |
| 204,800 |      0 | OverwriteAsNeeded |     362 | Windows PowerShell     |
+---------+--------+-------------------+---------+------------------------+
```

I'd like to avoid harcoding the log names. As seen via `Get-Help Limit-EventLog -example`, there's a better way with `ForEach`. However, in doing so it seems to apply `Limit-Eventlog` to the first log only and fail for the remaining 6. Note I've changed the value slightly (200MB to 100MB) so that it's easy to see where it fails.

```
$Logs = Get-Eventlog -List | Foreach {$_.log} 
 Limit-Eventlog -Logname $Logs -MaximumSize 100MB -OverflowAction OverwriteAsNeeded 
Get-Eventlog -List

+---------+--------+-------------------+---------+------------------------+
| Max(K)  | Retain |  OverflowAction   | Entries |          Log           |
+---------+--------+-------------------+---------+------------------------+
| 102,400 |      0 | OverwriteAsNeeded |   2,606 | Application            |
| 204,800 |      0 | OverwriteAsNeeded |       0 | HardwareEvents         |
| 204,800 |      0 | OverwriteAsNeeded |       0 | Internet Explorer      |
| 204,800 |      0 | OverwriteAsNeeded |       0 | Key Management Service |
| 204,800 |      0 | OverwriteAsNeeded |  10,399 | Security               |
| 204,800 |      0 | OverwriteAsNeeded |   3,563 | System                 |
| 204,800 |      0 | OverwriteAsNeeded |     369 | Windows PowerShell     |
+---------+--------+-------------------+---------+------------------------+
```

and the 6 errors:

```
Limit-Eventlog : The value supplied for MaximumSize parameter has to be in the range of 64 KB to 4GB with an increment of 64 KB. Please enter a proper 
value and then retry.
At line:2 char:5
+     Limit-Eventlog -Logname $Logs -MaximumSize 100MB -OverflowAction  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Limit-EventLog], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ValueOutofRange,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.LimitEventLogCommand

Limit-Eventlog : The value supplied for MaximumSize parameter has to be in the range of 64 KB to 4GB with an increment of 64 KB. Please enter a proper 
value and then retry.
At line:2 char:5
+     Limit-Eventlog -Logname $Logs -MaximumSize 100MB -OverflowAction  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Limit-EventLog], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ValueOutofRange,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.LimitEventLogCommand

Limit-Eventlog : The value supplied for MaximumSize parameter has to be in the range of 64 KB to 4GB with an increment of 64 KB. Please enter a proper 
value and then retry.
At line:2 char:5
+     Limit-Eventlog -Logname $Logs -MaximumSize 100MB -OverflowAction  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Limit-EventLog], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ValueOutofRange,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.LimitEventLogCommand

Limit-Eventlog : The value supplied for MaximumSize parameter has to be in the range of 64 KB to 4GB with an increment of 64 KB. Please enter a proper 
value and then retry.
At line:2 char:5
+     Limit-Eventlog -Logname $Logs -MaximumSize 100MB -OverflowAction  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Limit-EventLog], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ValueOutofRange,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.LimitEventLogCommand

Limit-Eventlog : The value supplied for MaximumSize parameter has to be in the range of 64 KB to 4GB with an increment of 64 KB. Please enter a proper 
value and then retry.
At line:2 char:5
+     Limit-Eventlog -Logname $Logs -MaximumSize 100MB -OverflowAction  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Limit-EventLog], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ValueOutofRange,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.LimitEventLogCommand

Limit-Eventlog : The value supplied for MaximumSize parameter has to be in the range of 64 KB to 4GB with an increment of 64 KB. Please enter a proper 
value and then retry.
At line:2 char:5
+     Limit-Eventlog -Logname $Logs -MaximumSize 100MB -OverflowAction  ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Limit-EventLog], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ValueOutofRange,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.LimitEventLogCommand
```

Comment: I see that there is an extra `Get-Eventlog -List` after your `Limit-Eventlog -Logname $Logs -MaximumSize 524288Kb -OverflowAction OverwriteAsNeeded` command. Did you execute the command like this or is that just an copy/paste issue in your minimal example?

Comment: As above, looks like a typo/paste error with your command. Personally I would use select to get the property values: `$Logs = Get-Eventlog -List | select -ExpandProperty Log` and also update your MaximumSize property to read `0.5Gb` as it's easier to understand than a big number in Kb.

Comment: Changed to MB instead of Kb, but the problem is still there. Updated to include the commands as I ran them. @JamesC.

Comment: Looks like I found the issue, but don't have the knowledge to fix it.


`Get-EventLog Application | Select-Object -First 3`

`$Logs = Get-Eventlog -List | Foreach {$_.log}`

`Get-EventLog $Logs | Select-Object -First 3`

Throws the error: Get-EventLog : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'LogName'. Specified method is not supported.

`$Logs = Get-EventLog -List | select -ExpandProperty Log`

`Get-EventLog $Logs | Select-Object -First 3`

Same convert error.

Comment: You're getting that error because you are passing an array to [Get-EventLog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1) not a string `[-LogName] <String>` (which means only a single log name at a time). Whilst [Limit-Eventlog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/limit-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1) can take an array of strings `[-LogName] <String[]>` -- the `[]` indicates an array (so it can accept multiple log names at time).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've tried this two different ways and both work as expected... both are doing the same thing, just using different syntax.

Passing an array of log names to `Limit-Eventlog`:

```
$Logs = Get-Eventlog -List | select -ExpandProperty Log
Limit-Eventlog -Logname $Logs -MaximumSize 0.5Gb -OverflowAction OverwriteAsNeeded -WhatIf
```

And using `foreach` to pass each Log name individually to `Limit-Eventlog`:

```
$Logs = Get-Eventlog -List | select -ExpandProperty Log
Foreach ($Log in $Logs) {
    Limit-Eventlog -Logname $Log -MaximumSize 0.5Gb -OverflowAction OverwriteAsNeeded -WhatIf
}
```

You'll need to remove `-WhatIf` when not testing.

Comment: Thank you, the foreach one works so will accept this as the solution. The other throws the same 6 errors as in the original question.

Comment: just for balance, the non Foreach works perfectly for my Windows 2012 servers.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there's always this:

get-eventlog -List | select log -ExpandProperty Log | foreach ( $_ ) {limit-eventlog -LogName $_ -MaximumSize 20480KB -OverflowAction DoNotOverWrite}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).